# Select Box not in line in IE

Tags: html, css, layout

Ok, didn't really want to ask this question as it should be quite a simple solution, but I've spent hours trying to resolve it to no avail.
I have a web page with a text box, and then a select drop down next to each other. In Firefox and chrome they line up fine next to each other, but in IE the select box sits higher than the text box. Theres is no CSS applied to this select box, or the text box.

[image]

This is an aspx page, the generate HTML source for this is:

```
<label for="ctl00_main_primaryEmail" id="ctl00_main_primaryEmailLabel">Primary Email: </label>
<input name="ctl00$main$primaryEmail" type="text" id="ctl00_main_primaryEmail" />
<select name="ctl00$main$acceptedDomainsDropDownList" id="ctl00_main_acceptedDomainsDropDownList">
            <option value="domain.com">domain.com</option>
            <option value="doamin1.com">domain1.com</option>
            <option value="domain2.com">domain2.com</option>
            <option value="domain3.com">domain3.com</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Can you post the source code for these elements?

Comment: That HTML works fine for me in IE7. Are you sure there isn't any css affecting this?

Comment: I see i'm going to have to go and double check my CSS, as far as I can see there isn't any except a margin and padding reset, but maybe i'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this issue was CSS related.
It was a border setting for the select element buried deep in the IE only stylesheet of the Blueprint Library, hence not showing up in firebug. For anyone else that comes across it, its this CSS for the select element

```
margin : 0.5em 0px
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using any CSS to reset the margins and padding across all tags? It's quite useful to start your stylesheet with something like:

```
    *,html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
```

This gets rid of many rendering inconsistencies between browsers (i.e. IE) and the extra CSS needed to provide padding/margins where actually needed tends to be minimal. With this "reset" rule in place the boxes line up in IE (6 & 7 tested), though the issues of different default font-sizes remains:

[alt text http://www.mikrogroove.com/stackoverflow/textbox_selectbox_alignment.gif](http://www.mikrogroove.com/stackoverflow/textbox_selectbox_alignment.gif)

Comment: Yeah, I am actually using this. Thought this might be involved in the issue, but maybe not

Comment: Your HTML does render the way you want when I test it - there must be something elsewhere in your CSS that causes the misalignment!

Comment: If you use the "inspector" in Firebug you can compare the CSS that gets applied to each element; that will make it easier to see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following code. This lines up perfectly, when testing in IE7.

```
<input type="text">

<select>
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
</select>
```

My guess is that some CSS styling from parent elements (`body`, `form`, parent classes) gets applied to one or both of these elements, but without seeing the source code, this is hard to judge.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try removing any styling and see if I can find out which one is causing it. Looking in firebug the only styles that seem to be applied are some font styles and setting the border and padding to 0.

Answer (score 0):

using a table for layout might help

Comment: I'd rather not, its not tabular data, I'm fine with using CSS to fix the issue, just not been able to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting your form in some surrounding markup. I commonly use definition lists, so the markup would be something like

```
<dl>
    <dt>
        <label for="ctl00_main_primaryEmail" id="ctl00_main_primaryEmailLabel">Primary Email: </label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <input name="ctl00$main$primaryEmail" type="text" id="ctl00_main_primaryEmail" />
    </dd>
    <dt style="display: none;">
        <label for="ctl00_main_acceptedDomainsDropDownList">Accepted Domains</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <select name="ctl00$main$acceptedDomainsDropDownList" id="ctl00_main_acceptedDomainsDropDownList">
            <option value="exchange.samcogan.com">exchange.samcogan.com</option>
            <option value="doamin1.com">domain1.com</option>
            <option value="domain2.com">domain2.com</option>
            <option value="domain3.com">domain3.com</option>
        </select>
    </dt>
</dl>
```

Then you can float/position the dt and dd elements to appear in a single horizontal row.

This approach, whether you use a dl, ul or other, gives better positioning in general.